# Errors importing pyql namespaces

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, quantlib

I can import many things as the code below shows, but if I uncomment the imports two that are commented out, I get errors

```
[idf@node1 cboe]$ python pandas_pyql.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas_pyql.py", line 33, in <module>
    from quantlib.instruments.api import EuropeanOption
  File "/home/idf/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quantlib-0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/quantlib/instruments/api.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .bonds import FixedRateBond, ZeroCouponBond
  File "quantlib/indexes/ibor_index.pxd", line 12, in init quantlib.instruments.bonds (quantlib/instruments/bonds.cpp:6651)
ImportError: /home/idf/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quantlib-0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/quantlib/indexes/ibor_index.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK8QuantLib9IborIndex21businessDayConventionEv
[idf@node1 cboe]$ 

[idf@node1 cboe]$ python pandas_pyql.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas_pyql.py", line 36, in <module>
    from quantlib.termstructures.yields.api import FlatForward
  File "/home/idf/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quantlib-0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/quantlib/termstructures/yields/api.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .bond_helpers import BondHelper, FixedRateBondHelper
  File "quantlib/termstructures/yields/bond_helpers.pyx", line 1, in init quantlib.termstructures.yields.bond_helpers (quantlib/termstructures/yields/bond_helpers.cpp:4617)
ImportError: /home/idf/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quantlib-0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/quantlib/termstructures/yields/rate_helpers.so: undefined symbol: _ZN8QuantLib14SwapRateHelperC1ERKNS_6HandleINS_5QuoteEEERKNS_6PeriodERKNS_8CalendarENS_9FrequencyENS_21BusinessDayConventionERKNS_10DayCounterERKN5boost10shared_ptrINS_9IborIndexEEES5_S8_RKNS1_INS_18YieldTermStructureEEE
[idf@node1 cboe]$ 


import quantlib.reference.names as nm
from quantlib.pricingengines.blackformula import blackFormulaImpliedStdDev


from quantlib.instruments.option import EuropeanExercise, VanillaOption
from quantlib.instruments.payoffs import PlainVanillaPayoff, Put, Call
from quantlib.models.equity.heston_model import HestonModel
from quantlib.pricingengines.vanilla.vanilla import AnalyticHestonEngine
from quantlib.processes.heston_process import HestonProcess
from quantlib.quotes import SimpleQuote
from quantlib.settings import Settings
from quantlib.util.converter import pydate_to_qldate, df_to_zero_curve

#from quantlib.instruments.api import EuropeanOption
from quantlib.pricingengines.api import AnalyticEuropeanEngine
from quantlib.processes.api import BlackScholesMertonProcess
#from quantlib.termstructures.yields.api import FlatForward
from quantlib.termstructures.volatility.api import BlackConstantVol
from quantlib.time.api import today, NullCalendar, ActualActual

from quantlib.time.date import (Period, Days)
from quantlib.mlab.util import common_shape, array_call
```

**EDIT 1**

This is my /usr/local/lib

```
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         16 Apr 24  2015 libczmq.so -> libczmq.so.1.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         16 Apr 24  2015 libczmq.so.1 -> libczmq.so.1.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     780174 Apr 24  2015 libczmq.so.1.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root        927 Apr 24  2015 libfix8.la
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         16 Apr 24  2015 libfix8.so -> libfix8.so.1.0.3
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         16 Apr 24  2015 libfix8.so.1 -> libfix8.so.1.0.3
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    7784908 Apr 24  2015 libfix8.so.1.0.3
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         19 Jul 17  2015 libgdiplus.so -> libgdiplus.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         19 Jul 17  2015 libgdiplus.so.0 -> libgdiplus.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root     424120 Mar  9  2015 libgdiplus.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root        939 Apr 24  2015 libhftest.la
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         18 Apr 24  2015 libhftest.so -> libhftest.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         18 Apr 24  2015 libhftest.so.0 -> libhftest.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    2834313 Apr 24  2015 libhftest.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     209608 Apr 24  2015 libkj-0.6-dev.so
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     334352 Apr 24  2015 libkj.a
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     359914 Apr 24  2015 libkj-async-0.6-dev.so
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     528718 Apr 24  2015 libkj-async.a
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root       1002 Apr 24  2015 libkj-async.la
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         22 Apr 24  2015 libkj-async.so -> libkj-async-0.6-dev.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root        936 Apr 24  2015 libkj.la
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         16 Apr 24  2015 libkj.so -> libkj-0.6-dev.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root      57925 Apr 24  2015 libkj-test-0.6-dev.so
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      71578 Apr 24  2015 libkj-test.a
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root        995 Apr 24  2015 libkj-test.la
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         21 Apr 24  2015 libkj-test.so -> libkj-test-0.6-dev.so
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     550804 Jul  3  2015 libpfring.a
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root     421488 Jul  3  2015 libpfring.so
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         24 Apr 24  2015 libPocoFoundationd.so -> libPocoFoundationd.so.30
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   10145915 Apr 24  2015 libPocoFoundationd.so.30
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         23 Apr 24  2015 libPocoFoundation.so -> libPocoFoundation.so.30
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    2006896 Apr 24  2015 libPocoFoundation.so.30
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         18 Apr 24  2015 libPocoJSONd.so -> libPocoJSONd.so.30
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    2318379 Apr 24  2015 libPocoJSONd.so.30
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         17 Apr 24  2015 libPocoJSON.so -> libPocoJSON.so.30
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     327936 Apr 24  2015 libPocoJSON.so.30
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         17 Apr 24  2015 libPocoNetd.so -> libPocoNetd.so.30
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    7169896 Apr 24  2015 libPocoNetd.so.30
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         16 Apr 24  2015 libPocoNet.so -> libPocoNet.so.30
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    1209648 Apr 24  2015 libPocoNet.so.30
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         18 Apr 24  2015 libPocoUtild.so -> libPocoUtild.so.30
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    3264471 Apr 24  2015 libPocoUtild.so.30
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         17 Apr 24  2015 libPocoUtil.so -> libPocoUtil.so.30
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     473760 Apr 24  2015 libPocoUtil.so.30
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         17 Apr 24  2015 libPocoXMLd.so -> libPocoXMLd.so.30
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    2927891 Apr 24  2015 libPocoXMLd.so.30
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         16 Apr 24  2015 libPocoXML.so -> libPocoXML.so.30
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     596408 Apr 24  2015 libPocoXML.so.30
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   54723484 Mar 27 13:42 libprotobuf.a
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root        972 Mar 27 13:42 libprotobuf.la
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    4638676 Mar 27 13:42 libprotobuf-lite.a
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root       1007 Mar 27 13:42 libprotobuf-lite.la
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         26 Mar 27 13:42 libprotobuf-lite.so -> libprotobuf-lite.so.10.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         26 Mar 27 13:42 libprotobuf-lite.so.10 -> libprotobuf-lite.so.10.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    2005147 Mar 27 13:42 libprotobuf-lite.so.10.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         21 Mar 27 13:42 libprotobuf.so -> libprotobuf.so.10.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         21 Mar 27 13:42 libprotobuf.so.10 -> libprotobuf.so.10.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   21758102 Mar 27 13:42 libprotobuf.so.10.0.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   96605238 Mar 27 13:42 libprotoc.a
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root        988 Mar 27 13:42 libprotoc.la
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         19 Mar 27 13:42 libprotoc.so -> libprotoc.so.10.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         19 Mar 27 13:42 libprotoc.so.10 -> libprotoc.so.10.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   32484516 Mar 27 13:42 libprotoc.so.10.0.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1025743748 Jun 12  2015 libQuantLib.a
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root        945 Jun 12  2015 libQuantLib.la
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         20 Jun 12  2015 libQuantLib.so -> libQuantLib.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         20 Jun 12  2015 libQuantLib.so.0 -> libQuantLib.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  365069474 Jun 12  2015 libQuantLib.so.0.0.0
```

This is my LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
[idf@node1 cboe]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/intel/lib/intel64:/opt/NAG/cll6i25dcl/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib:/usr/local/lib:/opt/intel/opencl/lib64:/usr/local/apr/lib:
[idf@node1 cboe]$
```

Comment: Do you have QuantLib installed? (You should have a `libQuantLib.so` file somewhere in your dynamic linker path.)

Comment: See EDIT 1 in original post.

Comment: Maybe the dynamic linker has an outdated cache. Try `sudo ldconfig` to refresh it.

Comment: Tried. doesn't help.

Comment: Last thing I can think of: a mismatch between the QuantLib version on which pyql is based and the one you have. Things might have been added (if your version is older) or deprecated and then removed (if it's newer).

Comment: Reinstalling Anaconda2 and pyql seems to have resolved the issue. Thanks.